# Navigation Menu PHP ECHO INSIDE ECHO

Tags: php, html, mysql, variables, navigation

I am making my navigation menu and i want to add an active class
here is my code

i want to output the CSTYLE and use 'if to echo the active class

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT CSTYLE,id, name, DESCRIPTION FROM menu where VISIBLE='1'   
ORDER BY `order` ASC") or die(mysql_error());               
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
printf('<li %s id="page_%s">%s %s </a></li> ', $row['CSTYLE'], $row['id'],  
$row['name'],$row['DESCRIPTION']);
}
?>
```

here is the content of CSTYLE

```
if ($thisPage=="HOME")  echo " class=\"active\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
  <?php
         $result = mysql_query("SELECT CSTYLE,id, name, DESCRIPTION FROM menu where VISIBLE='1'   
        ORDER BY `order` ASC") or die(mysql_error());               
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            if (strtolower($thisPage)==strtolower($row[2])) {
                printf('<li class="active" %s id="page_%s">%s %s </a></li> ', $row['CSTYLE'], $row['id'],  
            $row['name'],$row['DESCRIPTION']);
            }
            else
           {
                printf('<li %s id="page_%s">%s %s </a></li> ', $row['CSTYLE'], $row['id'],  
            $row['name'],$row['DESCRIPTION']);
           } 

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Sorry ... my bad... Please check the $row["property for page name"] == "HOME"
instead of $thisPage=="HOME"

Comment: $thisPage is the identifier of individual pages, have a look a this please http://alistapart.com/article/keepingcurrent# . Thanks

Comment: Can you please do var_dump($row) inside while loop and post that data to me ??

Comment: array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(19) "" ["name"]=> string(19) "" [2]=> string(4) "Home" ["DESCRIPTION"]=>

Comment: string(4) "Home" } array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "3" ["id"]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(39) "" ["name"]=> string(39) "" [2]=> string(12) "Virtual Tour" ["DESCRIPTION"]=> string(12) "Virtual Tour" } array(6)

Comment: { [0]=> string(1) "2" ["id"]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(24) "" ["name"]=> string(24) "" [2]=> string(10) "Learn More" ["DESCRIPTION"]=> string(10) "Learn More" } array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "4" ["id"]=> string(1) "4" [1]=> string(21) "" ["name"]=> string(21) "" [2]=> string(6) "Trivia" ["DESCRIPTION"]=> string(6) "Trivia" } array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "5" ["id"]=> string(1) "5" [1]=> string(21)

Comment: Please refer updated code, I have modified a code and it will add active class in current page